# image hyperlink not working in html

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

Regular links to other pages on a sidebar are working, yet when I try to hyperlink an image in the page's body nothing happens. Everything is in the same directory. Does this have anything to do with the page having a header div and sidebar with "display:fixed" and "z-index:1" ?

```css
#info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15em;
  margin-left: 12em;
  z-index: -1;
}
#info td {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0em 2em 0em 2em;
}
#info img {
  height: 15em;
  width: auto;
}
#link_title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="info">
  <h2> Tips & Tricks </h2>
  <table>
    <td>
      <p id="link_title">Cooking & Food Tips</p>
      <a href="tips_tricks_cooking.html">
        <img src="deceuillete_fraise.jpg" alt="strawberry" />
      </a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Try using your browser's development tools to see if the image has been loaded

Comment: May be it's css issue. another div or html element overlapping on your side bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image link is inside a div with a negative z-index - so it is not clickable.  You will need to remove the negative z-index from `#info`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `z-index:-1` in the `#info` it will be work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

z-index tells the browser the preference of layers within the html code. Remove the z-index or place it lower in the 'stack order' and it should work just fine. Also, just FYI, your table's missing the  tags.

The display:fixed will not affect other tags unless this section (pasted above) is within those tags, this will cause a conflict and errors